# Gnome vfs mount (eg. smb/cifs) via CLI

Tags: gnome, mount

Is there a way to mount a gnome-vfs bookmark (eg a samba/cifs share) via CLI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gvfs-mount smb://user@server.tld/share
```